# Trigger para sistema de imovel

Tags: banco-de-dados, trigger

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um sistema de imóvel e preciso que a cada cinco minutos o banco leia a informação do imóvel, processe e descriptografe a informação, envie uma confirmação de processamento e descarte a informação.
Estou pensando em fazer alguma trigger, mas não sei como liberar ela a cada 5 minutos, alguém pode me dar uma luz? (Desculpe a falta de tecnicidade, ainda estou começando)

Comment: Você pode usar `SQL Server Job`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você está pensando em executar uma ação no banco de tempo em tempo, vejo que a melhor opção seja utilizar "events"

```
Create event teste //bome
On schedule
Every 1 week //aqui é o intervalo
Do
NomeDaTrigger;
```

Com esse evento vc criar campo, deleta, executa procedures e triggers, de tempos e tempos pré definidos.